# How to print unsigned floating point in c

Tags: c

Actually am having value like **x = 1041039360** and **y = 93741056**.

When perform division in c program like **y/x i.e (93741056/1041039360)**, the answer is -0.090045641.

I want to remove (-) minus from the answer.

How to get it..??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef _SC_PHYS_PAGES


size_t getTotalSystemMemory(){
    long pages = sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES);
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    return pages * page_size;
}

size_t getFreeSystemMemory(){
    long pages = sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES);
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    return pages * page_size;
}
#endif

bool eat(long total,int chunk){
    long i;
    for(i=0;i<total;i+=chunk){
        short *buffer=malloc(sizeof(char)*chunk);
        if(buffer==NULL){
            return false;
        }
        memset(buffer,0,chunk);
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    printf("Currently total memory: %zd\n",getTotalSystemMemory());
    printf("Currently avail memory: %zd\n",getFreeSystemMemory());

    printf("Percentage: %f %\n",(
                    (getFreeSystemMemory()/1024*1024)/(getTotalSystemMemory()/1024*1024)
                )); 


}
```

Comment: What your actual output ? BTW `"Percentage: %f %\n"` should be `"Percentage: %f %%\n"`

Comment: All three format specifiers are wrong. Should be `%zu`, `%zu`, and `%zu` (or actually pass a `float` or `double`).

Comment: For printing multiply it with `-1` .

Comment: `(getFreeSystemMemory()/1024*1024)/(getTotalSystemMemory()/1024*1024)` can be reduced to `getFreeSystemMemory() / getTotalSystemMemory()` by removing items that are present in both the numerator and denominator. It would be a little bit faster and cleaner.

Comment: There is no unsigned floating point type in C (nor any other language using IEEE754).

Comment: you might try fabs() which requires #include <math.h>.   However, the code is accessing functions that are wrapped by a #ifdef _SC_PHYS_PAGES  so, if _SC_PHYS_PAGES is not defined, then the code does not compile as the accesses to those wrapped functions are access to undefined functions.   Even if the symbol is defined, the compiler will raise several warnings.   Suggest re-thinking the code logic, always compile with all warnings enabled, and re-post the corrected code

Comment: the function 'eat()' is not called in the posted code.  so why is it there?    the expression 'sizeof(char)' is specifically defined as 1, so has no effect on the call to malloc() so should be removed.

Comment: this kind of expression:  '/1024*1024'  (which happens to be =1) should be optimized out of existence by the compiler   The result of the division is then size_t/size_t (which happens to be a long int), so the format specifier in the printf() format string should be "%lu"   To get the expression to be effective, the code needs another set of parens:  similar to: ((getFreeSystemMemory()/1024)*1024)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this expression:

```
(getFreeSystemMemory()/1024*1024)/(getTotalSystemMemory()/1024*1024)
```

All subexpressions are of an integral type, so the result is also of an integral type.  The division operation is also integer division rather than floating point division because of that.  You are then trying to print that integral type as a float, which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to cast at least part of the above expression to a floating point type so that the rest of the expression is done in floating point:

```
((double)getFreeSystemMemory()/1024.0*1024.0)/((double)getTotalSystemMemory()/1024.0*1024.0)
```

That should print the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

after applying the needed corrections to the code, so it cleanly compiles, this is the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>




size_t getTotalSystemMemory(){
    long pages = sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES);
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    return pages * page_size;
}

size_t getFreeSystemMemory(){
    long pages = sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES);
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    return pages * page_size;
}



int main( void )
{


    printf("Currently total memory: %zd\n",getTotalSystemMemory());
    printf("Currently avail memory: %zd\n",getFreeSystemMemory());

    printf("Percentage: %lu %%\n",( ((getFreeSystemMemory()/1024)*1024)/((getTotalSystemMemory()/1024)*1024)));


}
```

running that code on my computer results in:

```
Currently total memory: 7167004672
Currently avail memory: 3325980672
Percentage: 0 %
```

The 0 percent is because of the integer divide.

To achieve a more useful percentage, change the print statement to:

```
printf("Percentage: %f %%\n",( ((getFreeSystemMemory()/1024.f)*1024.f)/( (getTotalSystemMemory()/1024.f)*1024.f)));
```

which results in:

```
Currently total memory: 7167004672
Currently avail memory: 3278430208
Percentage: 0.457434 %
```

or this:

```
printf("Percentage: %f %%\n",( (float)((getFreeSystemMemory()/1024)*1024)/ (float)( (getTotalSystemMemory()/1024)*1024)));
```

which results in:

```
Currently total memory: 7167004672
Currently avail memory: 3263479808
Percentage: 0.455348 %
```

Yet another needed improvement to the code is to display a percentage and not a fraction, so multiply the result by 100.f

```
printf("Percentage: %f %%\n",(( (float)((getFreeSystemMemory()/1024)*1024)/ (float)( (getTotalSystemMemory()/1024)*1024))) *100.f);
```

which results in:

```
Currently total memory: 7167004672
Currently avail memory: 3279790080
Percentage: 45.762356 %
```

Note: the available memory keeps changing because of the OS and background processes coming and going.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to remove the negative sign, you could check if the output is negative and negate if so or use abs().

```
float z = (float)(x/y);
if( z < 0){
   z = -z;
}
```

Also, it is worth noting that your final statement is unnecessary:

`getFreeSystemMemory()/1024*1024)/(getTotalSystemMemory()/1024*1024`

Consider this

```
x = getFreeSystemMemory();
y = 1024^2;
z = getTotalSystemMemory();

//then your statement becomes 
(x / y) / (z / y);
//which equals
(x / y) * (y / z);
//which equals
(x / z);
```

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? The OP question is: i want to remove (-) minus from the answer.

How to get it..??